# PHP - compare "now" to future date, and set $var if time has arrived

Tags: php, datetime

I'm not a total noobie to PHP but haven't worked a ton with dates. I'm trying to compare "now" in three Asian time zones against a future date (11/19/2019 10:00am) and set a $var if that time has passed.

I have revamped my code and this seems to work correctly, but seems more verbose than needed?

```
<?php
// now in each zone
$now530 = new DateTime("now");
$now530->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

$now800 = new DateTime("now");
$now800->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'));

$now700 = new DateTime("now");
$now700->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));

// presale start in each zone
$start530 = new DateTime("2019-11-19 10:00");
$start530->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

$start800 = new DateTime("2019-11-19 10:00");
$start800->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'));

$start700 = new DateTime("2019-11-19 10:00");
$start700->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));

// presale end in each zone
$end530 = new DateTime("2019-11-21 22:00");
$end530->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

$end800 = new DateTime("2019-11-21 22:00");
$end800->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'));

$end700 = new DateTime("2019-11-21 22:00");
$end700->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));

if ($now530 >= $start530 && $now530 < $end530) {
    $presale530 = true;
}

if ($now530 >= $start800 && $now800 < $end800) {
    $presale800 = true;
}

if ($now530 >= $start700 && $now700 < $end700) {
    $presale700 = true;
}

?>
```

Comment: And what's your question? Where's the code to apply different timezones? What do you mean by "if that time has passed"?

Comment: Just carefully step through your code: 1) `presale_time` is an integer 2) it's set in a "current" timezone, which is unknown (to us) 3) `$presale_time > $now530;` here you're trying to compare an integer with an object 4) `if (isSet($isPresale530)) {` given those are booleans - you don't need `isset`; `isset` is used to check if variable was defined, and in your case it always was.

Comment: "I'm trying to compare "now" in three Asian time zones against a future date (11/19/2019 10:00am)" --- against a future date _in what timezone_?

Comment: @Chris code made (above in OP). It works but seems verbose? Is there a better / shorter.

Comment: @KirkRoss yep, have a look at my answer: with using `format` you can reduce it almost twice.

Comment: @KirkRoss you can put everything in a single `try` as well https://pastebin.com/14qkTJbk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you actually tried to achieve is done with

```
$kolkata = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$shanghai = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'));
$jakarta = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));

$presaleTime = '2019-11-19 10:00:00';
$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

$isPresaleKolkata = $kolkata->format($dateFormat) > $presaleTime;

if ($isPresaleKolkata) {
    echo "Do Kolkala stuff";
}
```

Elaboration:

1. `Y-m-d H:i:s` format is comparable, so you can safely use string comparison with `>` and `<` operators
2. The time `2019-11-19 10:00:00` would be treated as local per every location
3. The condition `if ($isPresaleKolkata) {` would trigger if the current local time is **PAST** the presale time. If I got it wrong and it in fact should be **PRIOR TO THAT** then just swap the `>` with `<`

Comment: I refactored / created my code (above in OP). It works but seems verbose? Also, I get an unhandled exception when setteing date and timezone in the same statement. `$shanghai = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'));
`

Comment: @KirkRoss it works just fine for all php versions available on 3v4l down to 5.2 https://3v4l.org/TtpZr What an unhandled exception tells exactly?

Comment: Can you tell me how to accommodate older PHP. i.e. I can't just throw an error message, it *must* work.

Comment: @KirkRoss it's hard to suggest anything given you did not share the error message or your currently used php version.

Comment: Wouldn't it be necessary to set the presaleTime in all 3 timezones too?, e.g. `$presaleKolkatra, $presaleShanghai, $presaleJakarta`

Comment: @KirkRoss nope. It's just a string, you put semantics into that string yourself. It's compared with the local time. If I say "let's have a lunch together today at 12:30pm" - you see I didn't need to mention a timezone yet for you the statement is unambiguous. Print the `$kolkata->format($dateFormat)` value and I'm sure it'll click.

Comment: I have 10 minutes to chat if you need further explanation: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202530/discussion-between-zerkms-and-kirk-ross).